# Three virtual machines, one virtualhard drive for the same OS

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtual-desktop

Is it possible to create three different Virtual Machines, and use the same Virtual Hard Drive using same Operating System?

I will be installing a Windows 7 Professional OS at the Virtual Hard Drive, and then create three different users -- namely User 1, User 2, and User 3.

At the first VM, I will be using the same VHD, but log in as User 1. 
At the second VM, same setup, but will log in as User 2. 
And same with the third VM, but will log in as User 3.

Will this work? Or it will have errors since three different VMs will be accessing the same VHD?

Comment: How is this different than just having one VM with 3 users?  Using physical computers as analogy, this is equivalent to having one hard drive that you keep pulling out of one computer and inserting it into another each time the user changes.  If the VMs are identical, you could do it, but why?  If they are not identical, then Windows is going to complain each time you switch VMs.

Comment: so RAM usage of each User will be separate per VM. I don't know if this is a good reason though.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can do it-- as long as only one of the machines are on at a time-- but why do it?  In theory, Windows may complain (especially activation) if you change the number of vCPUs or RAM, but it won't always complain.  You'll also have to check the virtual disk file and make sure that all the users have permissions to it (if they're logging into separate accounts on the same physical host).